# How to set length for an stored procedure param

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Because of some considerations I'm using an stored procedure to insert an entity in DB.
Some of my fields may have more than 4000 character length, but the query generated by NH declares some nvarchar(4000) variables to pass the value of the parameters.
Is there any way to set the length of the stored procedure parameter?
my parameter mapping is like this:

```
<query-param type="System.String" name="ArticleBody" />
```

When I set the length property in this tag like this:

```
<query-param type="System.String" name="ArticleBody" length="20000" />
```

I get this error:
"The type initializer for 'News360.Common.Singleton`1' threw an exception."

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks & Regards

Comment: Check the inner exception - it will tell you more about the error.

Comment: The inner exception in "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." I know this error, it appear when there is any problem in creating SessionFactory instance. The error doesn't help. The problem is to find a way to set the length of the param. It seems that the "length" property is't the right way.

Comment: What does the inner exception say, @user1078853?

Comment: Dear Inuyasha the inner exception is "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.". The error was thrown when crating a singleton instance of the SessionFactory. in the cases that there is any error in mapping files (*.hbm.xml files) I have this error, so I think this is because of adding the "length" property to "query-param" tag, and it mean that this property is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the `<query-param>` element only supports `type` and `name` attributes.

The real issue is that you are using the wrong type. In fact i think you are also declaring your types wrong. The type attribute expects the values are presented on the first column of the tables found at **5.2.2. Basic value types** in the NHibernate reference.

So, use `StringClob` instead of `string` (instead of System.String).

cheers

Comment: Thanks dear Jaguar. I have changed the types to StringClob, but the result is the same. The query generated by NH declares some nvarchar(4000) variables to pass the values yet.

Comment: I think so. Now I'm splitting my large string to some 4000 character strings and concatenate them in the Stored Procedure. It's silly!

Comment: Using StringClob is the right way! I have changed my mapping, replacing "System.String" by "StringClob". But the right solution is to use StringClob wen setting the parameter for the query, like: "query.SetParameter("ArticleBody", articleBody, NHibernateUtil.StringClob)". Thanks dear Jaguar.